# 'Ain't no' problem

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

1. "I ain't no bad."
2. "He ain't no good."
3. "They ain't no bad."
4. "You ain't no bad."

Could I use 'ain't no' in every sentences like these or something else should replace this? Are they actually correct in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"No good" is a common expression; "no bad" isn't. For that reason, all of the phrases you list containing "no bad" sound wrong to me. So I would say only 2. ("He ain't no good") is plausible from your list as something that a native speaker would say. "I ain't no good" and "You ain't no good" are equally possible.

"No good" generally implies a judgment of morality or value. See the following entry from Merriam Webster:

> Definition of [no–good](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no-good)
>   :  having no worth, virtue, use, or chance of success ∙ a *no–good* scoundrel

(Note: in the example, "no-good" is hyphenated because it is used as an attributive adjectival phrase. When "no good" is used predicatively, as in your example, it is not usual to use a hyphen.)

Therefore, an expression like "He ain't no good" would not be a good way of saying "He is ill" (since that is not normally a value judgment). It would work better as a way to express "His character is bad."

If you don't know already, I think I should tell you that both "ain't" and [negative concord](http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/negative-concord) (using more than one negative word to convey a single logical negation) are very markedly colloquial: depending on the context, sentences containing "ain't no" might sound "folksy", "rustic", "urban" or "uneducated", but they will not sound "standard"/"neutral". So they would not be considered appropriate in any situation where using standard English is a requirement.

Statements about "correctness" in this area are generally highly colored by emotions, not fact. A number of people would insist that "ain't no" is always "incorrect", but I am sure you can find it in dialogue written by respected English authors, so it is not "incorrect" in the sense of being something that English speakers never say or write. It's only "incorrect" in the sense of being something that some native speakers *do* say, that others think they *shouldn't* say.

The equivalent phrases in a neutral register of English would be "He's no good," "I'm no good," "You're no good."

Comment: Do these phrases express physical and/or behavioral conditions ? 
As for
1. If I am physically or mentally ill, could I say "I ain't no good." ?
2. If someone's character is bad, could I use "He ain't no good" ?

Comment: @LuckyAl-Amin yes to both questions. And more. You can also say _no good at/for `Verb`-ing_: _He's no good at hunting_, or, in nonstandard dialect, _He ain't no good at hunting_.